# Is it possible to use a string parse string to capture two different time formats?

Tags: java, time, format, simpledateformat

I'm using Java 8.  I want to parse a string into a time (java.util.Date object) if the string is of the form "hh:mm p" (e.g. "3:00 am") or if the string is in a military time format (e.g. "15:00").  I'm unclear as to how to write an expression to capture an either/or scenario.  Right now, I'm just accounting for one of the two scenarios ...

```
        final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        try {
            final java.util.Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(session.getStartTime__c());
            startTime = new Time(startDate.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }   // try
```

Is there a way I can rewrite the above code to capture both scenarios in one format or do I need to test the string and then use a different format string depending on what my test works out to?

Comment: The way to do this is to try the first, and in the ParseException block try the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the first, and if that doesn't work, try the second

```
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    final DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat(...);
    java.util.Date startDate = null;
    try {
        startDate = dateFormat.parse(session.getStartTime__c());
        startTime = new Time(startDate.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       try {
         startDate = dateFormat2.parse(session.getStartTime__c());
       } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
       }
    }   // try
```

Comment: The second catch clause is resulting in a syntax error upon compilation.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for alerting me, I've fixed it!